# How to count used and free Licenses from 4 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables which holds information about our Licenses. We have our own installation packages to install applications, so the PackageName refers to this installation packages name. It is possible that we have the same package 3 times, the only difference between them is, that the first is english, the second is german, and the third is a multilanguage package

The tables are:

Licenses:  This table holds the information how many Licenses we bought to an application.

`LicenseID   int

PackageName nvarchar(50)

DisplayName nvarchar(200)

Bought      int`

Registrations: This table holds information about which application(only those which requires a license) is installed on which host
`LicenseID  int

Host       nvarchar(50)`

So far so good, but the problem starts now. In certain cases it is possible, that a license can substitute another license. For example if we have office 2010 licenses then we can use them to install office 2007 too. So i needed an other table, to store which license can substitue another license

Substitutions: in this table there is only information about which licenseID can substitue which one. So i mean if office 2010 has a LicenseID `1`, and Office 2007 has a LicenseID `2`, then in this table will stay `1, 2`
`LicenseID      int

SubstitutedLicenseID`

The 4th table is Associations: This table holds the information which packages belongs to the same license. This is needed because what if we have two packages to the same License? I mean if we have a package for Symantec Antivirus 10 with German Language, and we also have a package for Symantec Antivirus 10 with English Language, then i have to packages, to the same Software, so they have to use the same License.
`PackageName nvarchar(50)

LicenseID    int`

So in this case in this table will stay, if Symantec Antivirus has a LicenseID 5:
`Symnatec Antivirus 10 DE, 5

Symantec Antivirus 10 EN, 5

Symantec Antivirus 10 MU, 5`

So my question is, how can i count my Licenses? I tried to create a view or a stored procedure, but for me this is far to complicated. Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? From your description I can't tell how your Package and Registration tables would be relevant to license counting but if they are please elaborate.

```
create table License(ID int, Name varchar(200), Bought int)
create table Package(ID int, PkgName varchar(200), LicenseID int)

insert into License(ID,Name,Bought) values(1,'Office 2010',3)
insert into License(ID,Name,Bought) values(2,'Office 2007',2)
insert into License(ID,Name,Bought) values(3,'Office 2003',1)
insert into Substitute(ParentLicenseID, SubLicenseID) values(1,2)
insert into Substitute(ParentLicenseID, SubLicenseID) values(1,3)
insert into Substitute(ParentLicenseID, SubLicenseID) values(2,3)

select
    ParentLicenseID=l.ID,
    ParentLicenseName=l.Name,
    BoughtDirectly=coalesce(l.Bought,0),
    BoughtIndirectly=sum(coalesce(l2.Bought,0)),
    TotalBought=coalesce(l.Bought,0)+sum(coalesce(l2.Bought,0))
from
    License l
    left outer join Substitute s on s.SubLicenseID = l.ID
    left outer join License l2 on l2.ID = s.ParentLicenseID
group by
    l.ID,
    l.Name,
    l.Bought
```

[image]